# How to use selenium functions within the same tab ? (on python)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Here's thing is , im trying to make my program to type in pewdiepie in the search box and then play the first video there is (this is going to be evolved into something much bigger for a project , but this is the gist of it) . The thing is when it shows me the search results , its on the same tab and selenium functions don't seem to recognise it . 
How can i fix this ?

Here's the code i wrote so far :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()    
url = "https://www.youtube.com"
driver.get(url)

searchBar = driver.find_element_by_name("search_query")
searchBar.send_keys("Pewdiepie")
searchBar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

try:
   clickVid = driver.find_element_by_id("dismissable")
   clickVid.click()
   print("Video Found")  #Trying to see what's happening 
except:
   print("Cant Click")
```

It works partially , it goes to the next page (on the same tab)
and says "Video Found" but it doesn't click it

Comment: Instead of clicking on `dissmissable`, change the ID to `video-title`. I.e. `clickVid = driver.find_element_by_id("video-title")`

Comment: When I search in DevTool in Firefox object with ID `dismissable` then It shows 23 objects with this ID and first is not video but `<div>` which groups many videos and clicking this `<div>` gives nothing. You would have to click second element with this ID. OR better find other method to find video

Answer (score 2):

**My friend, this is the code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
url = "https://www.youtube.com"
driver.get(url)
searchBar = driver.find_element_by_name("search_query")
searchBar.send_keys("Pewdiepie")
searchBar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(5)
try:
   driver.find_element_by_id("video-title").click()
   print("Video Found")  #Trying to see what's happening
except:
   print("Cant Click")
```

After searching, I added the wait 5 seconds to load the page and click on the video

> time.sleep (5)

More information on Python sleep ().[PYTHON SLEEP()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/time/sleep)

When clicking on the video, I modified the code

1- The variable clickVid I deleted it

2- I changed the video ID from "dismissable" to "video-title". You can view the page source to see the video ID (I clicked on the video title)

3- I added the click immediately after finding the video ID

Comment: You can comment if there are any problems